# Show border control on hover

Tags: xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I've got a Border control, which holds an Image control. Basicly i want to show the Border control if the Image control is hovered.
Something similar to the css :hover effect.

What's the easiest way achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are *so* many ways to achieve this, and it all depends on what your setup is.

- Is it for just one isolated image, or do you want to be able to reuse this functionality elsewhere?
- Is your image inside a `DataTemplate` for a `ListView` or some other items control?
- Would you be OK by writing code-behind to achieve this, or preferably a XAML-only solution? (Hopefully the latter.)
- Etc.

If it's for just one image, you could handle the `PointerEntered` and `PointerExited` events on the image control to set the border's `BorderBrush` color to yellow (for example) and transparent, respectively. Since you said you're very new to XAML, this is the only "easiest" solution that I can offer. Maybe someone else can suggest other simple alternatives. Unfortunately, there is no ":hover"-like styling out of the box. You have to write this functionality yourself.

---

My preferred solution is to bundle this functionality up into some kind of reusable component. Some solutions that come to mind:

1. Create a `UserControl` housing a `Border` and `Image` with the necessary code-behind to handle pointer enter and exit events.
2. Create a new templated `ContentControl`, allowing you to set any arbitrary `UIElement` inside the `Border`. This also allows you to use `TemplateBinding`s to set things like the `BorderBrush` from outside the template.
3. Create a `Behavior` (Blend SDK) that can be attached to your `Border` that houses the necessary logic.

On the topic of the Blend SDK, solutions 1 and 2 can be achieved with zero code-behind if you make use of `VisualState`s and blend's `EventTriggerBehavior` and `GoToStateAction` to handle changing visual states on `PointerEntered` and `PointerExited` events.